# Why can't access to 'this' when using anonymous function expression in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript, just a question on 'this' when using anonymous function expression.

```
const testFunction = function () {
   this.xxx = xxx;
};
```

later I call it as:

```
testFunction()
```

and there will be an error, because we can't use 'this' in this case,

but isn't that 'this' refer to the window object?

Comment: Unless you are in strict-mode ...

Answer (score 0):

If your JavaScript is running in a web browser, under default circumstances, then `this` **will** be the `window` object.

```js
const testFunction = function() {
  console.log(this === window);
};

testFunction();
```

If [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) is enabled, then it will not.

> Not only is automatic boxing a performance cost, but exposing the
>   global object in browsers is a security hazard because the global
>   object provides access to functionality that "secure" JavaScript
>   environments must restrict. Thus for a strict mode function, the
>   specified this is not boxed into an object, and if unspecified, this
>   will be undefined:

```js
"use strict";
const testFunction = function() {
  console.log(this === window);
};

testFunction();
```